# Showing UIWebView in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

I have to show user feed in `UITableView` that is in `HTML`,It may contain image tag. My deployment target is `iOS 5`. So,I can't use `Autolayout`. Currently I am showing these feeds in `UITableView`, in that each cell contain `UIWebView`.But It slow down scrolling and due to re-rendering of each cell after finishing web view loading is not smooth. I google it and found some api as `RTLabel` and others but It doesn't support  HTML image tag. So please give some suggestion.

Comment: are you loading the images asynchronously?

Comment: images are in user html feed so I am not loading it explicitly its handled by UIWebView.